# How to find rotation invariant chessboard image using opencv findchessboard() function?

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

Hi I am working with detecting chessboard corners with opencv's find chessboardcorners() and that seems to work well with straight angled images of chessboard, but once the chess board is in rotated direction
or if the image is angled the function doesn't recognize the chessboard.Please can anyone suggest any workaround for this?

Comment: The function is for camera calibration, not literally to be used for detecting chessboards.

Comment: Compute gradient. Detect lines. Extract the fields. Confirm color.

Comment: Hi! The OpenCV findChessboardCorners() algorithm is not very good. Are you still interested in this problem? I'm working on the same problem and just solved it with my own implementation a fair bit better than OpenCV does. Not perfect yet though. While I find it inspiring to read http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5491.pdf, I think that the ultimate algorithm is still the one by Andreas Geiger: http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libcbdetect/

Comment: As of 2019 it works quite well - see https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/play-chess-with-a-webcam/blob/master/examples/opencv/chessboardcorners.py